# Angular material badge on mat-button-group css goes wrong

Tags: css, angular5, angular-material-5

When I try add badge on mat-button-toggle-group only half of it is displayed.

please find the following

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #filtergroup="matButtonToggleGroup" value="myCase">
    <mat-button-toggle value="myCase" matBadge="8" matBadgePosition="after">
        My Cases
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle>
        My Team
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/emrqojllmka?file=app%2Fbadge-overview-example.html

How can I make it display in a right way?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the cut-off you will need to override the `overflow` property on `mat-button-toggle-group`:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #filtergroup="matButtonToggleGroup" value="myCase" style="overflow:visible">
```

However, the badge will still be overlapped by the adjacent button toggle. To get around that you need to raise the z-index of the badge class:

```
.mat-badge-content {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

G. Tranter's answer worked perfectly with the exception that the CSS had to use ng-deep

```css
:host ::ng-deep .custom-mat-badge {
  .mat-badge-content {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf="toggleValue" and also specify the css class you are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).